# How to merge multiple citations (footnotes) when using Pandoc?

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I'm using Pandoc to convert markdown files to HTML format. I'm using Typora as the main editor and so I'm used to Typora's pattern of merging the same footnote. Such as the following:
[image: HTML generated by Typora]

However, if I use Pandoc CLI, with commands like:

```bash
pandoc  .\test.md -f markdown -t html -s -o test.html
```

then, the output is as the following:
[image: HTML generated by Pandoc CLI]

My question is, how can I use Pandoc to generate HTML with merged footnotes as Typora does? I have investigated the Pandoc documentation but I cannot comprehend the `filter` or other customization procedures. Maybe because I lacked a clear understanding of the technical aspects of Pandoc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible,¹ see https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1603.

¹ It's probably possible to do with a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html), but not trivial.